# Getting data from sql db into different drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of an `employee` and in that table I have `one column named birthdate` that stores `date in 2012/4/5 format`

In a php page I have `3 drop down menu called year, month and date`

Can anyone help me ...how to fetch date into 3 different drop down menu?? Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in your PHP code use split method like this:

list($y,$m,$d) = split("/",$dob); // 2012/4/5

then use $y, $m and $d value as you want.
```

Comment: thnx.. My code is now working fine..I have used explode("/", $dod); I think split and explode do the same job.

Comment: yes, both functions works same

Comment: Thnx @komal ... I have used split as well..found both works same...

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode functin for this:

```
 <body>
 <?php
 $date = '2012/4/5';
 $date = explode('/',$date);
 ?>
 <select name="year">
     <option value="year"><?php echo $date[0]; ?></option>
 </select>
 <select name="month">
     <option value="month"><?php echo $date[1]; ?></option>
 </select>
 <select name="day">
     <option value="day"><?php echo $date[2]; ?></option>
 </select>
 </body>
```